# Objective C: imageNamed loading non existing image

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-simulator, imagenamed

I use a loop to load images into an `NSMutableArray`. Each iteration loads an images using the `imagedNamed` function in `UIImage`: `[UIImage imageNamed:*name*];`.

However, I wanted to change some of the images. So I removed the images from the project and added the new ones. But when I run the app in the iOS-simulator, the old images appear. Even when I remove all images from the project, they still appear.

Can someone explain why this is happening, and how I can change it?

Comment: Reset the simulator, clean the build.. If nothing works, check image name to see they match with the ones you deleted.. Last, quit and reopen xcode..

Comment: The cache (and therefor old/wrong images) persisted even after I went to Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that XCode hasn't recognised the new resources and usually the only way to fix it is to delete the old resources from the build folder.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> cleans all targets and the build folder. This should fix it

Comment: Thanks, this worked better than Build > Clean (and if you hold option down you see the "Clean Build Folder...").

Answer (score 2):

Clean your project CMD + SHIFT + K (XCODE 4.3 and above).
sometimes reference of deleted items remains in the project and make sure that u reset your simulator also.

Answer (score 1):

Did you clean your project in XCode ? Sometimes when you change some resources like images, XCode doesn't copy the new ones one the simulator / device.

To do so, go to "Product" -> "Clean"

Answer (score 0):

delete app from simulator, clean project and make sure that image exist. Image name is case sensitive. It may see on simulator but on device image will not display